# Delete file from Apache/tomcat/bin which is created by Apache POI SXSSF workbook

Tags: java, excel, apache, apache-poi

I am using SXSSF workbook to create an export of data into excel in my code, which creates an excel file in the Apache/tomcat/bin folder automatically while

```
workbook.createSheet("")
```

This overloads the tomcat and brings down the application. 
I am unable to clear these excels from the /bin folder, i do not need it as the excel is being saved in a different location for future use. 
Is there any way to avoid creating this excel in /bin folder or delete it once the excel is saved in other location?

Answer (score 0):

Apache POI SXSSF codebase uses temp files to avoid using excessive memory. These temp files are written, by default, to the Java temp dir (-Djava.io.tmpdir=/tmp).
https://github.com/apache/poi/blob/trunk/src/java/org/apache/poi/util/DefaultTempFileCreationStrategy.java

You can modify the value of this system property or you can provide a custom TempFileCreationStrategy. The javadoc on https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/util/TempFile.html describes how to do this.